# What can I do with an iPhone and no service?

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch

I'm interested in developing software for the iPhone camera, but I don't currently own an iPhone and don't really want to pay for service.  If I were just doing general app development, I'd probably just pick up an iPod Touch, but the Touch doesn't have a camera.

I know I can walk into the AT&T store, buy an iPhone and immediately cancel service.  But what can I do with the resulting iPhone?  Can I:

1. ... develop apps for it using the native SDK?
2. ... download apps from the app store (over wifi)?
3. ... use it for everything that I can do with an iPod Touch?

More generally, is this just a bad idea for some other reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still develop on a phone after it's jailbroken.  You can also still develop on a phone after it has been unlocked.  The difference is important:

Jailbreak:  You can install applications not available in the app store.

Unlock: you can run the phone on other networks besides it's default carrier (AT&T when in the USA).

Note that you cannot at this time unlock an iPhone 3g running 2.2.1, which it almost definitely will be if you buy it new.  You can jailbreak both iPhone and iPhone 3G.

Also be aware that if you buy a new phone, AT&T will charge you $200 to get OUT of your new contract.  I think that goes down by 10 or 20$ each month, so that after a year, it's considerably less costly to get out of the plan.

What I suggest is buying a first generation iPhone on ebay or craigslist.  First generation iPhones can all be unlocked, irrespective of whether the previous owner put 2.2.1 on them.  Also they are much cheaper, have the camera and are totally fine for software development.  I was able to find decent first generation iPhones in Seattle just 2 months ago for about $250 - $350 dollars depending on details.   Unlocking/Jailbreaking takes a matter of minutes with QuickPwn, and the phone works great as a development platform.

Answer (score 4):

You could jailbreak it and use it on a non-standard plan and pay less money.

Comment: Can I still develop/download apps on a jailbroken phone?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your iPhone must be activated to be used as a target device in xcode. While it would be activated after purchase you would have problems if you cancelled your account and then needed to restore it at somepoint.

If you do wish to support the camera its possible to develop on an iPod Touch - the mechanism for taking a photo is identical to selecting a picture from the library, you specify the source (camera/library) and the rest is handled by the OS with your code receiving the final picture.

If your app is going to be very camera-centric you should invest in an iPhone, but if it's for minor functionality you can probably get by with a touch.

Answer (score 0):

> I believe your iPhone must be
>   activated to be used as a target
>   device in xcode. While it would be
>   activated after purchase you would
>   have problems if you cancelled your
>   account and then needed to restore it
>   at somepoint.

No it does not. You can jailbreak to start and it will work fine.